# Short Horror Story About Man Trapped In Tunnel Chased By Pig-Like Creatures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I've been trying to find again a short horror I read about 15-20 years ago in a horror anthology I absolutely was mesmerized by but I can't for the life of me remember the title or author anymore. I could've sworn the title had something to do with "Rabbit" in it, but am not having any luck finding it. The main gist of the story is this man meets a pretty girl in a bar, who I believe drugs him, he gets on a bus which takes him to this huge empty warehouse, with no exit, except into this maze like tunnel which the man hears something behind him snorting getting closer, he finds one door which opens, goes into the room to hide, and goes into this dark closet when the thing comes into the room. He thinks a bunch of leather coats are hanging around him. The door of the closet opens and it's the lady from the bar with these pig like creatures with her armed with knives. The man sees the "coats" in the closet are actually hanging human skins. I would really LOVE to find this story so I can read it again. If anyone has any information, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this is the story but I so enjoy telling people of the plot: A guy is a boxer and he wants to become a superheavyweight and so takes some weight gain pills. But he is in a hurry so he takes the whole bottle at once and becomes so heavy (not fat but dense) that he literally falls through the Earth's crust and ends up in the tunnels of the Mole Men. IIRC, they look pretty much like giant moles, not like the mole people from the movie. They do however stand like men and they are boxing enthusiasts and they use him as a sparring partner although they are much stronger than he is.

Comment: @Jeff If you think this is _the_ answer to the question, please provide the name of the story. If you don't think this is the answer, post it as a comment instead.

Comment: The pig creatures makes me think of William Hope Hodgson's "House on the Borderland" but its' not that. https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/3260