# 1960s comic book/graphic novel-type format maybe: Boxer takes too many weight-gain pills and sinks underground?

Tags: story-identification, comics

Off hand, the stupidest story I ever read and why I wondered even then why my mom bought me comic books or I guess slightly thicker sort of graphic novels (but I don't think this was exactly a graphic novel). The boxer wants to go up a weight class or something and figures if he takes the whole bottle of weight-gain pills at once he will gain weight faster which indeed he does; in fact, the surface of the earth no longer supports his mass (he becomes denser but not fat) and he falls through the surface deep underground.

The kicker is, he meets giant moles who want to use the man as a sparring partner and that becomes his fate -- boxing  against giant moles (not mole *people* but giant, intelligent rodents) underground.

EDIT: Looking at the artwork at the link the answer provided, they apparently were humanoid creatures, not giant moles. I remembered that part wrongly.

Comment: Likely the same story as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157245/short-horror-story-about-man-trapped-in-tunnel-chased-by-pig-like-creatures. No answer there, but could you take a look and see if any of the details match so that you can [edit] them into your question?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: No, my summary is pretty accurate and includes the main details. No knives, no human skins -- just giant moles and boxing. I expect it to be a TV series within the next year or so. I did find a comic book writer who also trained as a boxer who might have written the masterpiece: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Buscema

Comment: My apologies. The bit about the boxer is in a deleted comment. I'll cite it in a comment below. They said they saw it in a horror comic.

Comment: "A guy is a boxer and he wants to become a superheavyweight and so takes some weight gain pills. But he is in a hurry so he takes the whole bottle at once and becomes so heavy (not fat but dense) that he literally falls through the Earth's crust and ends up in the tunnels of the Mole Men. IIRC, they look pretty much like giant moles, not like the mole people from the movie. They do however stand like men and, dig this: they are boxing enthusiasts and they use him as a sparring partner although they are much stronger than he is. He is now trapped for the rest of his life in this situation."

Comment: sounds like the story but no name. there were horror comics which i think had self-contained stories as opposed to multiple stories with same characters. one creepy one i remember is a naval officer goes to an island of monsters and it turns out he is one them -- i have seen this theme many times. another is a guy summons a demon but accidentally made a gap in the chalk pentagram containing it when dragging his sorcerer uncle's body across the floor. point: some stories were okay, not all boxing moles.

Comment: I’ve removed a lot of the commentary from this post that isn’t really related to the question and some clarifications based on the answer. It’s fine to leave it as it is with misremembered details; even preferred in case someone else has also misremembered the same.

Comment: I think if I call the story "the stupidest story I ever read" I should be able to discuss the importance of boxing 60 years ago. But I can remove *all* the extraneous stuff, just make it really dull, if that would be better. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Please don’t add irrelevant commentary to the question. If you want to have a discussion take it to [chat] or some other discussion site. However, this question and answer site is not the place for such discussion, certainly so for a simple Id question.

Comment: the stupidity of the story is relevant and mentioning the context is therefore also relevant but i have bigger fish to fry -- i am selling some Nancy Pelosi stationery on ebay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [a reference to it on Google books here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/813_Heritage_Comic_Auctions_Comic_and_Co/eaMcQpCXCTYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=boxer+weight+pills+giant+moles&pg=PA151&printsec=frontcover). It's the story *Save Me From the Mole Men* by Paul Reinman in the comic [Tales to Astonish #16](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_to_Astonish_Vol_1_16):

[image: Mole Men]

> A boxer needs help to become a heavyweight, and breaks into an experimental lab to steal pills that hadn't been tested yet, but were supposed to make a person instantly gain wait. While escaping, he takes the entire bottle, and the building's floor can't hold his weight.
>
> He keeps falling through floors until he finds himself in the realm of the 'Mole Men', who immediately begin to beat on him. He dodges a few of their punches, and they become impressed with his speed. They imprison him and force him to become a sparring partner for all of them.

[It's a Marvel comic](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/11356/tales_to_astonish_1959_16) and Marvel have a free seven day trial for their online service that you can use to read it if you want.

Comment: Holy cow! After all these years -- and I had forgotten about his breaking into the lab; I think he slugs the security guard (what an ahole). I can hardly wait for the film or tv series (we get to know the mole men, and eventually the human has a romantic relationship with one of the female moles).

Comment: you know, his only hope is other humans will take whole bottles of weight gain pills because he can never return to the surface -- even if we wiped out the mole men, the boxer is stuck beneath the earth. but at least he would have company if other humans came.

Comment: whoever wrote the comment about weight loss pills, i did not mean to sound critical -- i was only kidding, please put your comment back if u want.